# How to exchange binary structured data over a stream for C++, Java and Python?

Tags: java, python, c++, stream, binary-data

## Explanation

I need to exchange binary structured data over a stream (TCP socket or
pipe) between C++, Java and Python programs.

Therefore my question:

**How to exchange binary structured data over a stream for C++, Java and Python?**

1. There is no way to create the complete object to be serialized beforehand - there must be the possibility to *stream in and stream out* the data.
2. Because of performance issues I need some binary protocol format.
3. I want to use (if possible) some existing library, because hand-crafting all the (de-)serialization is a pain.

## What I want

My idea is something like (for C++ writer):

```
 StreamWriter sw(7);  // fd to output to.

 while( (DataSet const ds(get_next_row_from_db())) ) {
    sw << ds;  // data set is some structured data
 }
```

and for C++ reader

```
StreamReader sr(9);  // fd for input

while(sr) {
   DataSet const ds(sr);

   // handle ds
}
```

with a similar syntax and semantics for Java and Python.

## What I did

I thought about using an existing library like Google Protocol Buffers, but this does not support stream handling and there is the need to create the complete object hierarchy before serialization.

Also I though about creating my own binary format, but this is too much work and pain.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: To those who closed this: I reformulated the question that IMHO it fits into stackoverflow rules. If you think there are still problems, please comment. If not, please reopen.

Comment: You are still asking for recommendation. Even if it ever gets reopened, it will be closed all of a sudden. Just let it go.

Comment: Sorry - I'm confused. IMHO I described the problem (section Explanation and 'What I need') and what have been done so far to solve it (section 'What I did'). I have a programming problem and asks for hints how to solve it. Why do you think I'm asking for a 'recommend or find a tool...'? I don't want a recommendation but a solution.

Comment: Which is primarily opinionated. Asking for recommendation, no matter how you package it, is off-topic. Please put energy into real questions rather than getting your software recommendation through. Alternatively, you can try the software recommendation SE site.

Answer (score 0):

The options are Apache Thrift, Google's protocol buffer and Pache Avro. Good comparison is there at http://www.slideshare.net/IgorAnishchenko/pb-vs-thrift-vs-avro

So I recommend you to try apache Avro.

Comment: The Google protocol buffer is old and unmaintained. The original author started a project called capnproto which oughta be better, but in general it would be better not to feed off-topic questions with answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend explicitly documenting how your data types are to be serialized, and writing serialization and deserialization code in each language as needed.  I have found in the past that with good documentation of how the data is to be serialized, this is fairly painless.

Your other major option is to standardize on one platform's default serialization method, but that means you have to figure out that method and implement in the other languages.  This tends to be trickier as the default serialization methods are often complex and not well documented.

Comment: Please do not feed off-topic questions with answers.

Comment: I don't think it's clear that this question is off topic.  Asking "is there a" is different from asking "please recommend a", as the former admits the possibility that there may be no magical solution and one might have to do more of the coding for oneself.  Note that my answer was not an opinion or recommendation on what tool or library to use.

Comment: From the closure reason: `"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."`

Comment: @LaszloPapp Looks like StackOverflow disagrees, since the question got reopened while you still felt it was off topic.

Comment: I do not see any disagreement. The question has been radically modified. Your answer still does not contribute much to me, however.

Comment: @LaszloPapp He edited the question 7 hours ago now.  You posted a comment on the question 6 hours ago now that said you thought it was still off topic.  Yet it still got reopened without any further editing.

Comment: I do not follow. The question got closed for the reasons I mentioned, and you were defending it was on topic. It was not in agreement with others. As for the reopen, there are many robo reviewers, it is a real problem on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @WarrenDew: Thank you for your answer. I cannot accept it, because - as said in the question - I do not want to handcraft my own serialization and maintain it.